# can you suggest a recipe for these hops and fermentables?

Tags: malt, brewing, pilsner

I can only find German pilsner malt for brewing in my country. I can find fuggles, saaz, brewers gold, cascade, Syrian,target 2014,HALLERTAU HERSBRUCKER types of hops. and I can find most common fermentis yeast types. what would you brew? or what recipe can you suggest to me with these ingredients?

Answer (score 2):

With only pilsner malt*, your options are pretty limited, but you are not helpless.

## [Pils](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style02.php), of course

What else would you brew if you have only malt designed for it? If you can keep low temperatures, go for it! With access both to saaz and German hops, you can try both German and Czech varieties.

## [Pale Ales](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style14.php) can work as well

Pilsner and pale ale malts are pretty much interchangeable, if you are not brewing pils itself. Sure, it won't be award-winning (probably), but you can get close enough.

## [Bitters](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style08.php)

They call for touch of black malt, but if you have oven and patience, you can turn some of your pilsner black on your own.

## [Dry Stout](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style13.php) seems doable as well

It calls for roasted barley in addition to pale malt. If you can just buy unmalted barley, roast it and here you go.

As you can see, you have pretty neat choice. Top and bottom fermentation, pale, red or black, you have a whole range in reach if you will put your heart into it.

---

* I find it really, really hard to believe that's the only thing you can find.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have an oven, you can make that pils malt into toast/roast specialty grains and go wild. See some suggestions by John Palmer to start and take it from there.

http://howtobrew.com/book/section-4/experiment/toasting-your-own-malt